# Relationship between Purity and Coherence of a quantum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, decoherence, coherence

I know that there is an important relationship between purity and coherence. Loss of purity is often used as a basis-independent sign of decoherence. I'm not completely sold on this.

I would have thought to be a sign of decoherence, that if we compared any two density matrices $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ in a Hilbert space, and the purity of $\rho_1$ is greater than $\rho_2$,that the magnitude of coherences of $\rho_1$ are greater than $\rho_2$ for any basis. But this can't be the case because the coherence of $\rho_1$ has to be greater in the eigenbasis of $\rho_2$.

So in what way is purity a sign of decoherence?